# Display list of post titles with specific tags at the beginning of current post

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I want, probably shortcode, that, if a chose this option for current post, displays  at the beginning of current post list of all posts with specific tag, posted before this post. Also, at the end of the post should be placed all posts that I will publish in the future with that tag. Is it possible? :)

```
<li>Title of first post with specific tag</li>
<li>Title of second post with specific tag</li>
.
.
.
<li class="current-post">This post title</li>

<li>Title of fourth post with specific tag</li>
<li>Title of fifth post with specific tag</li>
.
.
.
```

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, totally possible. You need to get the specific tag, feed that to a custom `WP_Query`. Also have a look at the post status parameters that you can use in your custom query

Comment: That sounds pretty difficult for me, because I'm not good at Wordpress. Some code would mean to me

Comment: I'm not able to code now unfortunately, posting from my phone. In the meantime, search for "related posts"